# ios app dosnt work when testing on a test device

Tags: iphone, ios

When I build the application to the testing phone everything works fine. If i then press the home button go back to the main screen then run the app , again everything works fine.

However if I quit the app to the home screen then close the application from running in the background and then try to run the app again from the main icon, it wont run it just goes to black screen and stops the phone from working or itll load the main view and none of the buttons work.. the only way to fix the phone so its usable again is to lock it and turn the device on again..

has anyone suffered this same issue before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the bootstrap server seems to get confused when you hit the home button and return to the app. If you are testing multi-tasking/background behavior, try the following process:

1. Build and run from Xcode.
2. Disconnect your device (your app will quit).
3. Now, truly quit the app by double tapping the home button and holding down on the app icon.
4. Finally, reopen the app and test for multi-tasking/backgrounding behavior (your won't get console messages however).

Comment: perfect.. worked a treat.. I thought I had thought of everything and was starting to think maybe its something in my code calling a server and hanging... was starting to go crazy! thanks very much will accept the answer once the time is up.

Comment: No problem, that issue definitely had me scratching my head before.